Calculating the partial derivative of distance between skew lines with respect to rotation vector
I am trying to minimize the distance between 2 lines by finding the Jacobian. but when i was trying to get the partial derivative $\frac{\partial d}{\partial \omega}$, it somehow ended up being a scalar instead of a 3 x 1. can anyone tell me where i went wrong?
Below is all of my work. go easy on me, been a long time since i did any math

Note: Assume all vectors and points are of shape $3 \times 1$
Given 2 lines defined by the points on the line $r_s$, $r_t$ and unit vectors to denote the direction $e_s$, $e_t$.
the unit normal vector between the lines is given by
$$
n = e_s \times e_t
$$
then the distance between the lines can be calculated by
$$
d = n \cdot (r_s - r_t)
$$
which is the project of the vector from $r_s$ to $r_t$ projected onto $n$ giving us the distance between them. Our aim is to decrease the distance between the lines. In order to do this we are going to transform on of the lines using a rotation matrix $R$ and translation $t$
$$
r'_s = R  r_s+t
$$
$$
e'_s = R  e_s
$$
Since $e_s$  is a vector only rotation $R$ is applied
$$
d = (e'_S \times e_t) \cdot (r'_s - r_t) \\ d = ((Re_s) \times e_t) \cdot(R r_s + t - r_t)
$$
$$
\frac {\partial d}{\partial t} = \frac {\partial}{\partial t} ((Re_s) \times e_t) \cdot(R r_s + t - r_t)) \\ \frac {\partial d}{\partial t} = ((R e_s) \times e_t) \cdot \frac {\partial }{\partial t} (R r_s + t - r_t) \\
\boxed {\frac {\partial d}{\partial t} = (R e_s) \times e_t }
$$
Now we need to parameterize $R$ using $w$ rotation vector
$$
R = \text{exp}([\omega]_\times) \\ [\omega]_\times = \begin{bmatrix}  0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\ \omega_z & 0 & -\omega_x \\ -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\ \omega = \begin{bmatrix} \omega_x & \omega_y & \omega_z \end{bmatrix}^T
$$
the exponential map can be approximated using Taylor series expansion
$$
\text{exp}([\omega]_\times) = \text{I} + [\omega]_\times + \frac {[\omega]_\times ^ 2}{2!} + \frac{[\omega]_\times ^3}{3!} +...
$$
when the transformation is very small you can ignore the higher power terms since they are close to zero
$$
\text{exp}([\omega]_\times) \approx \text{I} + [\omega]_\times
$$
let $A = (R e_s) \times e_t$ and $B = R r_s + t - r_t$ then
$$
\frac {\partial d}{\partial \omega} = \frac {\partial}{\partial \omega}(A \cdot B) \\ \frac {\partial d}{\partial \omega} = \frac {\partial A}{\partial \omega} \cdot B + A \cdot \frac {\partial B}{\partial \omega} 
$$
now the partial differential of $A$  w.r.t  $\omega$
$$
\frac{\partial A}{\partial \omega}= \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}((R e_s) \times e_t) \\ 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}(R e_s) \times e_t \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}(e_s + [\omega]_\times e_s) \times e_t \\= \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}( [\omega]_\times e_s) \times e_t \\ = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}( \omega\times e_s) \times e_t \\ \frac{\partial A}{\partial \omega}= e_s \times e_t
$$
now the partial differential of $B$  w.r.t  $\omega$
$$
\frac{\partial B}{\partial \omega}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}(R r_s + t - r_t) \\  = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}(R r_s) \\  = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}(r_s + [\omega]_\times r_s) \\  = \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}( \omega\times r_s) = r_s
$$
therefore
$$
\boxed{\frac{\partial d}{\partial \omega}= (e_s \times e_t) \cdot ( R r_s + t - r_t)+R e_s \cdot r_s}
$$

Notice that $A$ is a $3\times 1$ vector, and $\omega$ is also a $3\times 1$ vector, the "partial derivative" $\frac{\partial A}{\partial \omega^{T}}$ should be a $3\times 3$ matrix.
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial A}{\partial \omega^{T}}&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega^{T}}( \omega\times e_s) \times e_t \\ &= \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega^{T}}( \omega) \times e_s \right) \times e_t\\ &= (\mathbf{I}\times e_s )\times e_t,
\end{aligned}$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity tensor (or you can think of it as an identity matrix).
The "partial derivative" $\frac{\partial B}{\partial \omega^{T}}$ should also be a $3\times 3$ matrix.
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial B}{\partial \omega^{T}}&= \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega^{T}}( \omega\times r_s) \\ &= \mathbf{I}\times r_s.
\end{aligned}$$

If it's the indentity matrix. How does a product between $\text{I}$ 3 x 3 matrix and a 3 x 1 vector work? I am not able to make sense of this.

I think the dyadic tensor is what you need. Especially the Unit dyadic.
